# i am getting exception navigation failed because browser has disconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net, puppeteer-sharp

I'm getting an exception: *Navigation failed because browser has disconnected.*

After my code gets executed, it will close by the *using block*.

What is the main reason for the browser to disconnect?.

Here's the exception that I get:

> Error on finding navigate urls, screenshot and outgoing urls for Google id 78659 for location in in iteration 0 and error message is :
> PuppeteerSharp.NavigationException: Navigation failed because browser
> has disconnected! (NetworkManager failed to process
> Fetch.requestPaused. Frame 6CCD5A551750D9DF102ABCF53D90B6EB not found.
> at
> PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.AsyncDictionaryHelper`2.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0()

This is my code:

```
using (var destinationUrlBrowser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions))
    {
        using (var page = await destinationUrlBrowser.NewPageAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                var viewPortOptions = new ViewPortOptions{Width = 1366, Height = 768};
                await page.SetViewportAsync(viewPortOptions);
                await page.AuthenticateAsync(new Credentials{Username = _luminatiUserName, Password = _luminatiPassword});
                var timeout = new NavigationOptions{Timeout = 50000};
                Response response;
                try
                {
                    response = await page.GoToAsync(destinationUrl, 1 * 50000);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    response = await page.ReloadAsync(timeout);
                }

                await Task.Delay(2000);
                var pageSource = await page.GetContentAsync();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageSource) || pageSource.Contains("Proxy Error"))
                {
                    isDestinationPageSourceNotFound = true;
                }

                if (!isDestinationPageSourceNotFound)
                {
                    var screenShotOptions = new ScreenshotOptions{FullPage = true, Type = ScreenshotType.Jpeg, Quality = 50};
                    Log.Info($"Taking screen shot for {network} id {Id} for location {country}!");
                    await page.ScreenshotAsync(screenShotUrl, screenShotOptions);
                    var chain = response.Request.RedirectChain;
                    var redirects = new HashSet<string>();
                    for (var index = 0; index < chain.Length - 1; index++)
                    {
                        redirects.Add(chain[index].Url);
                    }

                    destinationInfo.Redirects = redirects.ToList();
                    var currentUrl = response.Request.Url;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        response = await page.GoToAsync(currentUrl);
                        var currentUrl1 = response.Request.Url;
                        if (currentUrl != currentUrl1)
                        {
                            currentUrl = currentUrl1;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentUrl = currentUrl1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    destinationInfo.DestinationUrl = currentUrl;
                    Log.Info($"Found {destinationInfo.Redirects.Count} redirect urls from {network} id {Id} for location {country}!");
                    destinationInfo.HtmlPageSource = pageSource;
                    using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter(indexHtml))
                    {
                        await outputFile.WriteAsync(pageSource);
                    }

                    destinationInfo.HtmlContent = Helper.RemoveStyleAndScript(destinationInfo.HtmlPageSource);
                    using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter(htmlContentUrl))
                    {
                        await outputFile.WriteAsync(destinationInfo.HtmlContent);
                    }

                    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(basePath, zipPath);
                    destinationInfo.LocalHtmlPath = zipPath;
                    destinationInfo.LocalScreenShot = screenShotUrl;
                    outgoingUrls = Helper.GetOutgoingUrl(pageSource, currentUrl);
                    Log.Info($"Found {outgoingUrls.Count} outgoing urls from {network} id {Id} for location {country}!");
                    foundDetails = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Info($"Error on finding navigate urls, screenshot and outgoing urls for {network} id {Id} for location {country} in iteration {iterate} and error message is : {e}");
                if (iterate > 1)
                {
                    isDestinationPageSourceNotFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing I see: If your authentication fails, you catch an exception, ignore it, and just keep going like nothing is wrong.  You might want to reconsider that logic.

Answer (score 4):

If your code used to work, and it stopped working all of a sudden.

You won't believe it! Chrome version matters so basically if you are using 
Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit), it will fail and show "Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!" Error.

downgrade your chrome to Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit) or below 7X.XX.XXXX.XXX

Note: Make sure you do the same in your server as well. Not just locally